How can I convert Interval Difference to Circle of Fifths segments and position
How to convert Interval Difference to Circle of Fifths segments and position
Hi, Im designing a numeric decimal notation code model for exploring math relations between notes on chromatic scales and circle of fifths.
The model uses numeric identifiers instead of letters.  So for example "G" is represented as " 1.50 ".
Have a problem which Im guessing is likely easy for most of you out there well versed in music theory - would love feedback on this and pointers to a solution.  My hope is to end up with a simple straight forward math formula / function that can be used.
Description ; Given two musical notes, determine the distance between note 1 and note 2 on a standard scale, 7 or 12 based scale and then convert this distance to the number of segments on the circle of fifths separating the values.
For example, here we have two notes ;
NOTE 1 = 1.483  ( G )
NOTE 2 = 1.428  ( F # )
Distance between n1 : n2 = 1.93 ( B # )
where ; 1.483 * 1.93 = 1.428
Using this value of 1.93, we want to derive the number of segments that separate NOTE 1 & NOTE 2 on the circle of fifths, which is 4.0
The notes are assigned their numerical values ( not lettered names ), so for example instead of labelling the note "G", here the decimal numeric equivalent is used such that ; 2^(7/12) = 1.5, in the case of the examples given ; 1.48 ~ ( 2^(6.82/12) ), and 1.428 ~ (2^(6.16/12)), the note values given are irregular

If I look visually at the circle of fifths such as via this link ;
https://randscullard.com/CircleOfFifths/ and from the left column labelled "Tonic" click on the G note, I can see that the "F#" is four segments clockwise from the "G"
Each segment has the equivalent of 7 semitones to equal a p 5th and 1.496^11 = 7 * 12
But the function, formula I am hoping for is one where I can input the distance between two notes and get as an output the equivalent number of segments of the circle, in the case of the above example this should be ;
1.93 = 4.0
Where 1.93 is the distance on a scale between note 1 and note 2 and 4.0 is the distance between the notes on the circle of fifths.  The math function should use the values of note 1, note 2, distance ; 1.48, 1.428, 1.93, to compute the number of segments on the circle ; 4.0
Can anyone provide some direction on this?
Much thanks
D

I suspect that the "leap frog" mechanism outlined on this link is involved somehow, except for the effect I am after this would possibly be some kind of reversal of the effect mathematized, see ; https://www.music-theory-for-musicians.com/circle-of-fifths-scales.html

it might help if you can explain more where you are getting the numerical values for the notes from

the numeric values are decimal notations derived via 2^(x/12), where x is some number between 1 to 12 but where x may be a real number and not just an integer.

how is x derived?

Hi Dr M, X is any real number between 1.00 and 12.00, where as the normal values would be integers between 1 to 12, here Im using values that can represent irregular or regular pitches, so instead of X equaling just "2" it could be 2.25 as ; 2^(2.25/12)

@AstroD: What are you planning to do with the fractional semitone values?  Explore non-12-ET tuning systems?  Numerically quantify "how dissonant" an interval is based on its Circle of Fifths distance?  Knowing your purpose could help improve the answers.

Possibly useful w.r.t. this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3627550/11994

If I understand your system correctly, your numbers are just the 12-ET frequency ratio relative to C, i.e.,

C = $1$
C♯/D♭ = $2^{1/12} \approx 1.059$
D = $2^{1/6} \approx 1.122$
D♯/E♭ = $2^{1/4} \approx 1.189$
E = $2^{1/3} \approx 1.260$
F = $2^{5/12} \approx 1.335$
F♯/G♭ = $2^{1/2} \approx 1.414$
G = $2^{7/12} \approx 1.498$
G♯/A♭ = $2^{2/3} \approx 1.587$
A = $2^{3/4} \approx 1.682$
A♯/B♭ = $2^{5/6} \approx 1.782$
B = $2^{11/12} \approx 1.888$

To find the interval between two notes, first find the number of semitones between them.  If $x$ is the lower note and $y$ is the higher one, then:
$$\boxed{s = 12\log_2\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} \approx 17.31234\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
For example between F and B, we have:
$$s = 12\log_2\left(\frac{1.888}{1.335}\right) \approx 6$$
You'll want to round to the nearest integer to account for rounding errors in the frequencies.

Now, on to the Circle of Fifths.
In the original version of this answer, I gave the formula $\boxed{f = (7s) \bmod 12}$ (where $f$ is the number of fifths, and $s$ is the number of semitones), but that only works for 12-ET.  So, I'll generalize
Let $w$ be the width of a perfect fifth interval, as a fraction of an octave.  The value of $w$ depends on the tuning system.

In Pythagorean tuning, $w = \log_2 \frac{3}{2} \approx 0.584963$
In 12-ET, $w = \frac{7}{12} \approx 0.583333$.
In 19-ET, $w = \frac{11}{19} \approx 0.578947$.
In 31-ET, $w = \frac{18}{31} \approx 0.580645$.

More generally, a syntonic temperament allows $w \in [\frac{4}{7}, \frac{3}{5}] = [0.\overline{571428}, 0.6]$.  In theory, you could define $w$ outside this range, but that would lead to weirdness like E being higher than F, flats being higher than sharps, or major intervals being wider than minor ones, so let's not do that.
Instead, let's define the Circle of Fifths distance of an interval $x$ (expressed as a fraction of an octave, so $x = \frac{s}{12}$) as the minimum distance to reach a frequency ratio with perfect fifths:
$$f(x) = \min \{ |n|: (nw - x) \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{Z}, \frac{4}{7} \le w \le \frac{3}{5} \}$$
Or, as an explicit piecewise function of $x$:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 && x = 0 \text{ or } x = 1\\
1 && \frac{2}{5} \le x \le \frac{3}{7} \text{ or } \frac{4}{7} \le x \le \frac{3}{5} \\
2 && \frac{1}{7} \le x \le \frac{1}{5} \text{ or } \frac{4}{5} \le x \le \frac{6}{7} \\
3 && \frac{1}{5} < x \le \frac{2}{7} \text{ or } \frac{5}{7} \le x < \frac{4}{5} \\
4 && \frac{2}{7} < x < \frac{2}{5} \text{ or } \frac{3}{5} < x < \frac{5}{7} \\
5 && 0 < x < \frac{1}{7} \text{ or } \frac{6}{7} < x < 1 \\
6 && \frac{3}{7} < x < \frac{4}{7}
\end{cases}$$
Or, in terms of traditional interval nomenclature (with 12-ET semitones):
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 && \text{P1 (0) or P8 (12)}\\
1 && \text{P4 (5) or P5 (7)} \\
2 && \text{M2 (2) or m7 (10)} \\
3 && \text{m3 (3) or M6 (9)} \\
4 && \text{M3 (4) or m6 (8)} \\
5 && \text{m2 (1) or M7 (11)} \\
6 && \text{A4 (6) or d5 (6)}
\end{cases}$$
Note that under this revised formula, every interval has the same CoF distance as its octave inversion.

Reasonable guess as to the OP's intent. Hard to say for sure though, it's pretty murky.

Finally, this is clearly the best, most comprehensive and detailed reply I have seen.  Thank you so much for this lucid explanation!  I understand most of what you described above - do you mind if I ask a few other questions related to this?  I am hoping to create some routines in Excel and scripts in python to model this.

@Dan , using your example of 1.888 and 1.335, in Excel I compute as ; log((1.335/1.888)*2,2)*12 = 6 so here I have the same result you illustrated above, so 6 steps on the 12 step chromatic scale.  So if I understand, hopefully, how to transpose as you have instructed, I take "6 fifths = 42 semitones" and in Excel I would write mod(42,12)=6. so also 6.  1.888~B# and 1.33~F, so on the wheel of fifths I should see 6 steps between B# and F.  If I refer to the online circle of 5ths calculator at link italic bold and designate the "F" as the root...

(continued from previous) it does look like there is approx 6 steps between the notes.... am I on the right track, am I understanding this correctly or am I in error in any way?

@AstroD: It looks like you're correct. except that the frequency ratio should be high/low instead of low/high.  But that's just a sign error, giving an interval of -6 semitones instead of +6.

Dan, seriously awesome - thanks so much for this.  Taking the high/low into consideration, then I can use the above process to determine the steps on the circle of 5ths then between any two notes - is this correct?

@AstroD: Correct.  Assuming that the interval is a whole number of 12-ET semitones and not some weird microtonal thing.

Tried a variation on your method above, does this clock to what you are saying ; given that there are 84 semitones in the circle of fifths via ; 1.496^11=83.99 and using the following notes ; 1.799 ( Bb) and 1.108 (Db), 1.108/1.799 = 1.232, then ; log(1.232,2)*84 = 25.28,  then mod(25.28/7,12) = 3.61, there fore on the circle of fifths the notes Bb and Db are separated by 3.61 steps, does that look correct?

@AstroD: Where did you get those numbers for B♭ and D♭?

@ Dan ; Bb ; 2^(10.16 / 12)  and Db ;  2^(1.77 / 12 )

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

thanks Dan, I clicked on the link you provided and sent some follow up questions

Thank God, Dan showed up!  He patiently helped me correct some of my own misconceptions about the nature of the problem and provided lucid and constructive solutions.  Have been able to test out his concepts in code and they work!  Awesome, much thanks to him and to this forum.  Cheers

Hi Dan, you asked ; "@AstroD: What are you planning to do with the fractional semitone values? Explore non-12-ET tuning systems? Numerically quantify "how dissonant" an interval is based on its Circle of Fifths distance? Knowing your purpose could help improve the answers. "
Yes, all of the above - my goal was to be able to create a simple code model so I could view these relationships via the console and display output

@AstroD: I see.  Well, then, I'll have to edit my answer later to consider alternative tuning systems.

@AstroD: Does this revised answer adequately answer your question?

Apologies for late reply, yes this helped a lot, thank you!
